# Holding a really heavy object in front of you

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram, statics

If you have inhuman strength, is it possible to hold an object way heavier than you with your arms forward horizontal while standing with no anchoring? Or will the object simply make you fall forward due to balance?

Comment: Where is the center of gravity and where are your feet located with respect to that center of gravity?

Comment: The overall center of gravity is in front of your feet, check out my reply to Kristoffer.

Comment: If you don't move your feet such that you keep the center of gravity over your base of support (i.e., a rectangle the width of your feet's length and as long as the distance between the outsides of your feet), you will topple over due to a net torque, regardless of how strong you are.

Answer (score 1):

When you stand straight your center of mass is located in your stomach region. If you stretch your arms or in front of you, your center of mass moves forward a bit. If you hold something in your outstretched hands, the center of mass of you and the object together is even further forward. The more massive that object is, the farther forward the center of mass moves.

If the center of mass ever moves out beyond where your toes end, you'll topple over forward.

Comment: That seems legit. But my question is, can you apply a force with your hands such that the object doesn't move but the overall center of mass falls closer to you? Or because the center is beyond your toes you can't basically apply that force?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly, but the only way to move the center of mass is to redistribute the mass of you and the object. You can pull the object closer, or you can stick out your leg or, well, your butt to move the center of mass backwards.